# Changes to bash shell script language?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, syntax

i wrote a multipart script that calls rsync a few years ago and it has always worked.  After a year of no use and alot of debian apt-get updates, now the script stopped working.

Main2Network1.sh calls Main2Network2 there are parts 3 & 4 but the scripts Main2Network1.sh line 27 with:

```
 Main2Network1.sh: [[ not found
```

Line 27 is

```
if [[ -z $VAR ]];
```

When i wrote the script the script the [[ ]] were necessary for the if then to work with just pressing the enter key i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20201920/9383998

maybe someone can tell me if they see any recently deprecated syntax in my code around line 27 (thats where i get an error running script)  thanks all

Main2Network1.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash
#renames files changed files on NETWORK to _day_mnth_yr_NETWORK1 then puts maincomp version of file on network.
#THIS SHOULD BE PUT TO AUTOMATICALLY RUN AFTER TRAVEL2NETWORK SYNC
#info=NAME1 lists just changed Files/Dirs, -b must preceed --suffix,
# this will change existing dup file on travel to date_TRAVEL replacing base file with network version
#SOURCE File Dups replace network and network copy renamed to _NETWORK1
echo "source MAIN dir?"
read SOURCE
SO=$(echo ${SOURCE}/ | tr -d "[='=]")
echo "destination NETWORK dir?"
read DEST
DE=$(echo ${DEST}/ | tr -d "[='=]")
echo "exclude file?"
read EXCLUDE
EX=$(echo ${EXCLUDE} | tr -d "[='=]")
echo "=========================================="
echo "Exclude is $EXCLUDE"
echo "rsync destination is $DE"
echo "rsync Source is $SO"
echo "rsync exclude is $EX"
echo "=========================================="
mkdir "${0%/*}"/`eval date +"%d"_%m_%Y`log/
LOG=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)/`eval date +"%d"_%m_%Y`log/
# ~/ issue
rsync -aEv --info=NAME1 -c -n --numeric-ids -z -b --suffix=_%d%m%Y_%H%M_NETWORK1 --exclude-from=${EX} ${SO} ${DE} > $LOG/Main2NetworkStep1LOG.txt

echo 'check output if acceptable continue?'
read VAR
if [[ -z $VAR ]];
then
     echo "backing up Main To Network"
     echo ==================================================
     source /`dirname $0`/Main2Network2.sh
     echo 'Main System backed up'
else
    echo "Ok"
    exit
fi
```

Main2Network2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
DAY=`eval date +"%d"`
MONTH=`eval date +"%m"`
YEAR=`eval date +"%Y"`
echo 'beginning REAL Main to network backup'
echo ================================================================
rsync -aEv --info=NAME1 -c --numeric-ids -z -b --suffix=_${MONTH}_${DAY}_${YEAR}_NETWORK1 --exclude-from=${EX}  ${SO} ${DE} > ${LOG}/Main2NetworkRealBackupStep2Log.txt
echo 'all done Main to Network sync'
leafpad ${LOG}/Main2NetworkRealBackupStep2Log.txt
echo 'begin Network to Main backup process?'
echo ========================================
read VAR
if [[ -z $VAR ]];
then
     echo "Generating Network to Main Backup Dry Run Report"
     source /`dirname $0`/Main2Network3.sh
else
    echo "Ok"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Is the first character of `Main2Network1.sh` a blank, or is that a cut and paste artifact?

Comment: Try to reduce your script to a minimal failing example, i.e. the smallest snippet of code that you can make fail. At the moment, it's full of extraneous irrelevant code.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases this is because the script is run as `sh Main2Network1.sh`, which ignores the shebang line.

Comment: This script has a bunch of bad practices (esp. failure to double-quote variable references). I recommend running it through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: @l0b0 you are totally right....simple is usually most direct solution huh...still unsure why previous years sh and bash were acceptable to this script, but simple solution solves the bigger problem - TY

Comment: @debdragon Debian used to use `bash` as /bin/sh (so entering the command `sh` would actually get you `bash`), but in version 6 (Squeeze) they switched to `dash`, a much more basic shell, as /bin/sh. That's probably why it used to work, but doesn't anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me, returning true if "just enter" is hit, or any number of spaces, or a few tabs.  Any alphanumeric, etc. returns false.

```
if [ -z $VAR ]
then
 ..... do your backup stuff here
else
  "ok, not backing up"
fi
```

FWIW I'd change the prompt to make it more clear to "just hit enter to run the backup, any character(s) to exit"

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is on the very first line of `Main2Network1.sh`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
#renames files changed files on NETWORK to _day_mnth_yr_NETWORK1 then puts maincomp version of file on network.
```

See that stray space at the start? That turns your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line into just another comment, so the kernel defaults to running your script with `/bin/sh`, which doesn't understand the `[[ ]]` construct.

Remove that space, and all should be well.

Comment: ugh - that makes total sense ... never caused an issue before - maybe a line spacing - will try - @Adrian

Comment: yeah the space at the start didn't fix things - removed the space and still same result.   @l0b0 was spot on that now sh and bash must not be used with bash scripts...bash scripts can now just be run by file name and location alone....ie  dragon:~#/home/ftpd/networkbakup.sh

Comment: @debdragon What does `file Main2Network1.sh` say?